# jSlot - Can we make the first number never land on 0?

Tags: jquery, random

I'm using this jquery jSlots (https://github.com/matthewlein/jQuery-jSlots) using numbers 0-9. Is there any way I can make the end result to never land on 0 for the first li?

Clarity:

0129 = Bad

1029 = Ok

Comment: Can you show us your current code?

Comment: @Blue Boy https://jsfiddle.net/chc7p4xt/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've updated some of the javascript code, it should be impossible to get a 0 on the first number now, but let me know if you do:

https://jsfiddle.net/chc7p4xt/7/

Updated parts:

1

```
    // clone lists
    for (var i = base.options.number - 1; i >= 0; i--){
         base.allSlots.push( new base.Slot(i) ); //sends i
    }
```

2

```
    // Slot contstructor
    base.Slot = function(i) { //recieves i

        this.spinSpeed = 0;
        this.el = base.$el.clone().appendTo(base.$wrapper)[0];
        this.$el = $(this.el);
        this.loopCount = 0;
        this.number = 0;
        this.count = i; //sets i

    };
```

3

```
    if(this.count == 5) //checks if its the first number
    {
        var endNum = base.randomRange( 1, base.liCount - 1 ); //if so, can't be 0
    }
    else
    {
        var endNum = base.randomRange( 1, base.liCount );
    }
```

Edit: To answer your question in the comments:

```
    if(this.count == 5) //checks if its the first number
    {
        var endNum = base.randomRange( 8, base.liCount - 1 ); //Changed the 1 to an 8
    }
    else
    {
        var endNum = base.randomRange( 1, base.liCount );
    }
```

Comment: No problem, glad to help :)

Comment: quick question, would it be possible to set the first number to be only number 1 or 2?